# Часть веб-приложения на vue, часть на html

Tags: php, html, vue.js

Пишу пет-проект на php, клиентскую часть отдаю html страницами, а админскую часть хочу написать на vue. Понимаю что это какое-то извращение, но хотелось бы узнать возможно ли вообще такое и какие пути реализации вы видите. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, читайте документацию по Vue, на такие вопросы там точно есть ответ.

Comment: Вы можете на любой странице, в любое время любой из элементов сделать VUE компонентом. Это дока https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn а это пример как работает https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/nw1xg8Lj/ просто вставьте этот код в свою html страницу и вы все поймете, чтобы сделать больше элементов одновременно, укажите им другие id